# can we put multiple different data in append row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
var range = sheet.getActiveRange()

var data1 = sheet.getRange(4,2,1,3).getValues()
var data2 = range.getValue()
sheet.appendRow([data1[0],null,null,1,data2]) // fix this line, can't we?
```

I want appendRow only 1 row and with all data1 ... data2. I'm not sure how to put it correct way

I did try but it didn't work, it appended "[Ljava.lang.Object;@79bbb3e2" for "data1[0]"

but for "null,null,1,data2" was doing fine

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GcyfutUP-vg23H9mpjfNLRQvTkOqp0c8dN-J4R8g9Hk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: data1 is a 2 dimensional array, instead of `data1[0]`, try `data1[0][0]`.

Comment: @Ted you should add it as a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var data1 = sheet.getRange(4,2,1,3).getValues()` refers to the data in the range "B4:D4". This is a two dimensional array.

In your `appendrow` statement, try the value `data[0][0]` instead of `data[0]`.

**UPDATE**

So the complete statement would be:
`sheet.appendRow([data1[0][0],data1[0][1],data1[0][2],null,null,1,data2])`

Comment: I try sheet.appendRow([data1[0][0],null,null,1,data2]) but "data1[0][0]" but it returns a single value, not values as getValues(). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @zummon Please share a copy of your spreadsheet, and include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: thank you very much, this is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GcyfutUP-vg23H9mpjfNLRQvTkOqp0c8dN-J4R8g9Hk/edit?usp=sharing